# multiprocessing + logging + tqdm progress bar flashing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, tqdm, python-logging

Can someone experienced with `tqdm` help me with the following reproducer please?

```
import itertools
import logging
import multiprocessing
import random
import sys
import time

import tqdm
from tqdm.contrib import DummyTqdmFile

log: logging.Logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


DEFAULT_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)06d][%(processName)s][%(threadName)s][%(levelname)s][%(module)s] %(message)s"
VERBOSITY = 1


def configure_logger(log: logging.Logger, verbosity: int, *, format: str = DEFAULT_FORMAT, dry_run: bool = False):
    """Configures the logger instance based on verbosity level"""

    # can't use force=true as it requires Python >= 3.8
    root = logging.getLogger()
    for handler in root.handlers:
        root.removeHandler(handler)

    if dry_run:
        format = format.replace(" %(message)s", "[DRY RUN] %(message)s")
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", stream=DummyTqdmFile(sys.stdout))

    verbosity_to_loglevel = {0: logging.WARNING, 1: logging.INFO, 2: logging.DEBUG}
    log.setLevel(verbosity_to_loglevel[min(verbosity, 2)])

    if verbosity >= 4:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    if verbosity >= 5:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def by_n(iterable, n):
    """Iterate by chunks of n items"""
    return (tuple(filter(lambda x: x is not None, x)) for x in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)] * n))


def _worker(batch):
    log.info("Let's go!")
    for i in batch:
        log.info("Processing item %d", i)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.2))
    log.info("Done!")

    return len(batch)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configure_logger(log, VERBOSITY)

    log.info("Let's go!")

    foos = list(range(1000))
    kwargs = {
        "desc": "Processing...",
        "total": len(foos),
        "leave": True,
        "mininterval": 1,
        "maxinterval": 5,
        "unit": "foo",
        "dynamic_ncols": True,
    }
    pbar = tqdm.tqdm(**kwargs)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as workers_pool:
        for batch_length in workers_pool.imap_unordered(
            _worker,
            by_n(foos, min(10 + int((len(foos) - 10) / 100), 1000)),
        ):
            pbar.update(batch_length)

    log.info("Done!")
```

When I set `VERBOSITY = 0`, the `log` calls from the worker processes output nothing and the progress bar is displayed correctly.

However, as soon as I log from the worker processes by setting `VERBOSITY = 1`, then here's what happening

- While the progress bar is properly positioned and sticks to the bottom of the screen
- Most of the time displays a progress of `0%` and only occasionally it flashes with the proper progress and percentage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will partially help. This concerns progress in multiprocessing.
After doing some research, I wrote a small module called [parallelbar](https://github.com/dubovikmaster/parallelbar). It allows you to display both the overall progress of the pool and for each core separately.
It is easy to use and has a good description.

For example:

```
from parallelbar import progress_imapu
from parallelbar.tools import cpu_bench


if __name__=='__main__':
    # create list of task
    tasks = [1_000_000 + i for i in range(100)]
    progress_imapu(cpu_bench, tasks, core_progress=True)
```

[image]